# Determine the spectrum of a shift-operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset \mathbb C$ be a sequence such that $|a_n|=r$ for all $n \geq 1$ and $r \geq 0$

Define $T: \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ by

$T(x_1,x_2,x_3,...) = (0,a_1x_1,a_2x_2,....) $ with $(x_1,x_2,....) \in l^2$

Determine the spectrum of T.

The spectrum of an operator is defined as $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: T-\lambda I  \ \text{is not invertible}\}$

I know how to calculate the eigenvalues of a matrix, but here I have really no idea to start.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  How do we define the *spectrum* of linear operator $T$?

Comment: I edited my post with the definition

Comment: Okay, so $(T-\lambda I)$ applied to $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ gives a sequence of complex numbers.  Can we reconstruct $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ from that sequence?  For simplicity, start with the case $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: What do you mean by reconstruct? We are getting $(-\lambda, a_1x_1-\lambda,....)$ aren't we?

Comment: No, $\lambda I$ applied to $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ is $(\lambda x_1, \lambda x_2,\ldots)$, not $(\lambda,\lambda,\ldots)$.

Comment: hmm then we get $(-\lambda x_1,a_1x_1- \lambda x_2,...)$ ?

Comment: Right, so the problem is, for what $\lambda$ are we *unable* to invert the mapping, i.e. unable to reconstruct the original sequence $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note first that $\|T\|=r$, and so $\sigma(T)\subset\{\lambda:\ |\lambda|\leq r\}$.

It is very easy to check that $T$ has no eigenvalues. This makes it usually easier to deal with $T^*$. We have 
$$
T^*x=(\overline{a_1}x_2,\overline{a_2}x_3,\ldots).
$$
Assume $|\lambda|<r$. Define a sequence $\{c_n\}$ by $c_1=1$ and  $c_{n+1}=\dfrac{c_n}{\overline{a_n}}$ and put $x=(\lambda c_1,\lambda^2c_2,\lambda^3c_3,\ldots).$ Then $x\in\ell^2$, since $|c_n|=r^{n-1}$ and so 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2=r\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac\lambda r\right|^n<\infty.
$$
Now
$$
T^*x=(\overline{a_1}x_2,\overline{a_2}x_3,\ldots)
=(\overline{a_1}c_2\lambda^2,\overline{a_2}c_3\lambda^3,\ldots)
=_(c_1\lambda^2,c_2,\lambda^3,\ldots)=\lambda x.
$$
So all such $\lambda$ are eigenvalues of $T^*$. We obtained
$$
\{\lambda:\ |\lambda|<r\}\subset\sigma(T^*)\subset\{\lambda: |\lambda|\leq r\}.
$$
As the spectrum is always closed, we get $\sigma(T^*)=\{\lambda:\ |\lambda|\leq r\}$. Finally, since the spectrum of $T^*$ is obtained from the spectrum of $T$ by conjugating the elements, we have 
$$
\sigma(T)=\{\lambda:\ |\lambda|\leq r\},
$$
that is, $\sigma(T)$ is the ball of radius $r$ centered at zero.

Comment: I had to handle with a similar exercise and your answer was very helpful! Although I would appreciate if you could help me understand the last step of your proof. I know $\;σ(T^*)=\overline {σ(T)}=\{ \; \bar z \in \mathbb C: z \in σ(T)\}\;$. How do I proceed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's just that $T-\lambda I$ is invertible if and only if its adjoint is invertible.

Comment: You say $\;z \notin σ(T)\;$ iff $\;z \notin σ(T^*)\;$, don't you? But this means $\;σ(T)=σ(T^*)\;$. Is this true? What am I missing here?

Comment: Nope. The adjoint of $T-zI $ is $T^*-\bar z I $.

Comment: Oh yes! My mistake! Got it now! Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: You are welcome :)